# Pointer Arithmetic with structures

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

How to print a particular member of a structure using pointer arithmetic? I have a structure with 2 members. I want to print out member `j` by manipulating the memory of the pointer to that structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct ASD
{
    int i;
    int j;
}asd;

void main (void)
{
    asd test;
    asd * ptr;

    test.i = 100; 
    test.j = 200;
    ptr = &test;

    printf("%d",*(ptr +1));

    _getch();
}
```

Comment: there is no such thing as 'the memory of the pointer'. Perhaps you meant 'manipulate the pointer'?

Comment: Why would you want to do this, rather than use the `->` operator?

Comment: I believe the intended third sentence was “…manipulate *the address stored in* the pointer…”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer type needs to be right so that the increment adds the correct size:

```
printf("%d",*( ((int*)ptr) +1));
```

**Edit:** As any C programmer should know, using pointer arithmetic to access struct members is useless and dangerous. Useless because the `->` operation is much more concise and precise in accessing a named member, and dangerous because naive use of pointer arithmetic will result in a number of issues. However, pointer arithmetic is what the OP asked for, so pointer arithmetic is what he got.

Comment: what if struct is `struct foo{ char d; int v; }`, then you'll have to re-edit the line.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: Depends on the padding. Have no idea why the OP wants to use pointer arithmetic to access members (instead of `->`), so I hope the question doesn't arise.

Comment: This is non-standard and so should not be preferred!

Answer (score 11):

Use the `offsetof` macro provided in `stddef.h`:

```
#include<stddef.h>

main()
{
    asd foo = {100, 200};
    unsigned char* bar = (void*)&foo;
    printf("%d\n", *(int*)(bar+offsetof(asd, j)));
}
```

Any other way runs into padding/alignment issues.